# Android ViewModel with Fragments causing the same data to be populated in different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I recently switched to Android MVVM on one of my Projects, the problem that I am facing is that with my Fragments used with ViewPager and TabLayout the data for each tab must be different based on an id of each tab, however since I am using AndroidViewModel to connect to my data source, the same data is shown in all my tab fargments. I understand that problem is that same ViewModel is shared between all the dynamic fragments[Fragmnet Class being the same].
Is there any way around this? or if I am doing something wrong.

//Code that returns data

```
private MutableLiveData<List<InventoryProduct>> inventoryProductList;

//we will call this method to get the data
public LiveData<List<InventoryProduct>> getCategoriesList(String cat_id,String store_id) {
    //if the list is null
    if (inventoryProductList == null) {
        inventoryProductList = new MutableLiveData<>();
        //we will load it asynchronously from server in this method
        loadInventoryProducts(cat_id,store_id);
    }
    //finally we will return the list
    return inventoryProductList;
}
```

Comment: show us the code please

Comment: Use different viewmodel for each fragment

Comment: The Fragment class is same with multiple[dynamic] instances created based on a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with having the same ViewModel for multiple fragments, in fact, it helps in a lot of ways. In your case, I would suggest that keep some identifier in the fragment, which you can pass to the ViewModel's function and accordingly decide what data to provide. This way different fragments would have different data and your data would still be persistent as long as the LifeCycleOwner is alive.
Following from the edited question, you will need to remove the null check, as the same instance of ViewModel is being used, once initialized, inventoryProductList is never null again and hence the subsequent functions are getting the data of the first fragment. As a solution(If you don't want to go the DB way), you can maintain a Map of the LiveData like this

```
Map<CatId/StoreId,LiveData<List<InventoryProduct>>> dataMap=new HashMap();
```

Now Instead of null check, you check the map for your CatId/StoryID (based on what key you have already used) and if the Map does not have the value already, go for the API call, otherwise return the value from the map.

Something like this
Say you had used StoreID as the Key

```
 if(!dataMap.containsKey(store_id)){
            MutableLiveData<List<InventoryProduct>> inventoryProductList = new MutableLiveData<>();
            //we will load it asynchronously from server in this method
            loadInventoryProducts(cat_id,store_id);
            dataMap.put(store_id,inventoryProductList);
//You need to post the response from the api call in this inventoryProductList

    }

    return dataMap.get(store_id);
```

Make sure that once you get the API response for the corresponding cat_id/store_id, you actually post the data to the corresponding LiveData.

Comment: Yes, I am already passing the identifier to the fragment and from there to the ViewModel loadData method, but still only the first data is thrown in all the Fragments via observable.

Comment: Can you paste the code which actually returns the data?

Comment: Please check, I have updated the Question with added code.

Comment: Thanks.
This I guess might work, as logically this will return the corresponding data to the Fragment. I was however looking for any solution in the architecture itself. I was wondering if I was doing something wrong, but looks like I have to proceed with this fix for now.

Comment: If you try to add a database and save the responses based on cat_id & store_id in that case, you can use Rooms LIveData feature to subscribe to the corresponding LiveData as required by the fragment. Please have a look over here if you need more information on that. (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel/#0)